# Find the Derivative of $f(x) = 5t - 9t^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck on this one:

$$f(x) = 5t - 9t^2$$

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{5(h+a) - 9(h+a)^2-5a-9a^2}h$$

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{5(h+a) - 9(h^2+2ha+a^2)-5a-9a^2}h$$

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{5h-9h^2-18ha-18a^2}h$$

I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: Due to a lack of parentheses on line two, your simplification is wrong.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot... Thank you!

Comment: Due to a lack of coherence in the variables, the answer should be $0$ ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're required to use the definition of the derivative only to solve this problem. But, if you need to use it, you can also use the derivative shortcuts to check your answer. So the derivative of $ f(x) = 5t-9t^2$ is $f'(x) = 5-18t$ You put the exponent in the front and subtract by one... $f(x) =5(1)t^{1-1} -9(2)t^{2-1} \rightarrow f(x) =5t^0-18t \rightarrow f(x) =5-18t$. Once you mastered the technique you can do these derivatives in your head :)...except for the quotient rule...not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{5(h+a) - 9(h+a)^2-(5a-9a^2)}h$$

instead of

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{5(h+a) - 9(h+a)^2-5a-9a^2}h$$

When you have the limit definition always remember the brackets. You should think of it like this so you don't make mistakes in the future

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - (f(x))}{h}$$

Also, as the comments have mentioned your function takes value of $x$ but is defined with $t$'s. You should instead write $$f(t) = 5t - 9t^2$$ and it will make a whole lot more sense to someone who is looking at your work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the sign error in writing $-5a-9a^2$ instead of $-(5a-9a^2)$, you are using the variables $x$, $t$, and $a$ interchangeably.  If it's not clear why it's a mistake to do so, please ask and I (or someone) will elaborate.